# Datatables Multi Select Column filter

Tags: jquery, datatables, html-table

I want to Select multiple items in a column filter. The following example allows you to filter on columns using  dropdowns:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

However, I would like to be able to select multiple items in the column filter, possibly with a checkbox beside each item in the dropdown. e.g. in the example, I would Tick 'A' and 'C' for 'CSS grade' so that only these grades are displayed in the table.

How can I get multi select column filters either using the DataTables plugin or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your own filter div with selectlists,checkboxes and whatever and use [fnFilter](http://datatables.net/ref#fnFilter) to request filtered data from the server. For example:

```
$("#mycheckbox").click(function () {
     var dt = $('#mytable').dataTable({ "bRetrieve": true });
     dt.fnFilter($("#mycheckbox").is(':checked'), 1);
});
```

Posts:

```
sSearch_1 : true/false
```

Comment: Hi, could I have a quick fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is really easy, asked in various ways multiple times - but surprisingly I could not find an exact match. If you have a that corresponds to your columns :

```
<select class="form-control" id="ddlSearch">
    <option value="0">Name</option>
    <option value="1">Position</option>
    <option value="2">Office</option>
    <option value="3">Age</option>
    <option value="4">Start date</option>
    <option value="5">Salary</option>
</select>
```

then implement this javascript to get seacrh in seperate columns

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#example').DataTable({
        pageLength: 100,
        dom: 'lrtip',
    });
    var column_no = 0;
    $('#ddlSearch').on('change',function(){
        column_no = Number($(this).val());
    });

    $( '#txtSearch' ).on( 'input', function () {
        if ( table.columns([column_no]).search() !== $( '#txtSearch' ).val() ) {
            table.columns([column_no]).search( $( '#txtSearch' ).val() ).draw();
        }
    } );
});
```

for example try this https://jsfiddle.net/07rnpgs1/

All the best

Answer (score 0):

You may check out [this](https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter) DataTables plug-in. It provides multiple criteria selection per column, as well as union selection across several columns.

Here is the short working **DEMO**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 //Source data definition 
 var tableData = [{
   name: 'Clark Kent',
   city: 'Metropolis',
   race: 'cryptonian'
  }, {
   name: 'Bruce Wayne',
   city: 'Gotham',
   race: 'human'
  }, {
   name: 'Steve Rogers',
   city: 'New York',
   race: 'superhuman'
  }, {
   name: 'Peter Parker',
   city: 'New York',
   race: 'superhuman'
  }, {
   name: 'Thor Odinson',
   city: 'Asgard',
   race: 'god'
  }, {
   name: 'Jonathan Osterman',
   city: 'New York',
   race: 'superhuman'
  }, {
   name: 'Walter Kovacs',
   city: 'New Jersey',
   race: 'human'
  }, {
   name: 'Arthur Curry',
   city: 'Atlantis',
   race: 'superhuman'
  }, {
   name: 'Tony Stark',
   city: 'New York',
   race: 'human'
  }, {
   name: 'Scott Lang',
   city: 'Coral Gables',
   race: 'human'
  }, {
   name: 'Bruce Banner',
   city: 'New York',
   race: 'superhuman'
  }
 ];
 //DataTable definition 
 window.dataTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
   sDom: 'tF',
   data: tableData,
   columns: [{
     data: 'name',
     title: 'Name'
    }, {
     data: 'city',
     title: 'City'
    }, {
     data: 'race',
     title: 'Race'
  
   }]
 });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/js/mfilter.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.mfilter.tk/css/mfilter.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting but your example probably doesn't work properly, there are no column filtering elements.

Comment: Click filter icon

Comment: There is no filter icon, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyJOf.png).