# How to add multi-select filter support to the header, dataTables 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have been searching for relative posts: [Datatables Multi Select Column filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582225/datatables-multi-select-column-filter) , [How to add additional filters to Datatables header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549952/how-to-add-additional-filters-to-datatables-header) but it does not solve my problem.

I use [dataTables 1.9](http://legacy.datatables.net/examples/) (legacy one), where I need a filter header exactly at the header like excel does [image]

which will provde a litter button and and then pop up a multi-select(with check boxes) filterer the rows.

So, I need two thing:

1. a little button to the header and a multi-select displays after click
2. column filter after multi select close.

Is there a plugin or any simple way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to write you desire html in `dataTable` `"fnRender": function (oObj) {}` and return that `html`.

```
aoColumns: [{
    "sName": "ColumnName", sType: 'string', sWidth: '5%', "fnRender": function (oObj) {
        var html = '<select>' +
                    '<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>' +
                    '<option value="saab">Saab</option>' +
                    '<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>' +
                    '<option value="audi">Audi</option>' +
                    '</select>';
        return html;
    }
}]
```

`html` will be added to your desired cell.

Comment: I need a multi-select rather than single select, and I need a callback method to filter the cells